# PySpark UDF work on sample set but not on large data

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My udf works on 1000 sample of my data but not on the entire set. I can't figure out whether it's my udf problem or my spark set-up problem.

Here is my data:

```
data =(spark.read.load('data.parquet/'))
data.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
data.printSchema()
    root
     |-- text_id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

I have a udf called tm that looks like this:

```
out_schema = StructType([
    StructField('GARAGE', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('ATTACHED', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('DETACHED', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('CARPORT', FloatType(), True),
])
@f.udf(out_schema)
def tm(text):
    """ 
    input some text. e.g." 2 GARAGES ATTACHED, 2 ATTACHED CARPORTS, DETACHED 1 CARPORT"
    perform a series of re.findall() and if/else statements
    return a list of numbers e.g. [2,2,NULL,2]
    """
    return tm_list
```

Then I passed this udf to a Pyspark Dataframe column:

```
garage_All = data.withColumn('extract_garage_nums',tm(f.col('text')))
garage_All.show() # this command always works on sample data, sometimes worked on entire data
garage_All.select('*','extract_garage_nums.*').dropna(subset=['GARAGE','ATTACHED','DETACHED','CARPORT'],thresh=1).show() # works on sample data, never works on entire
garage_All.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("data_output.parquet") # never works on entire data
```

I got the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e7f2e0bb0ec6> in <module>
----> 1 garage_All.show()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    378         """
    379         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    381         else:
    382             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o87.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 352, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 142, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 341, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: toInternal(f(*a))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-8-db7094f4c5f6>", line 53, in tm
TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 352, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 142, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 341, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: toInternal(f(*a))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-8-db7094f4c5f6>", line 53, in tm
TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I am using aws ec2 instance r5a.4xlarge and here's my pyspark setup:

```
spark = (SparkSession
        .builder
        .appName('Garage')
        .config('spark.executor.memory', '120G')
        .config('spark.driver.memory', '120G')
        .config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '10G')
        .config('spark.worker.cleanup.enabled', 'True')
        .config("spark.local.dir", "/tmp/spark-temp")
        .getOrCreate())
```

this syntax really confuses me since my udf works on 1000 sample of my data:

```
 File "<ipython-input-8-db7094f4c5f6>", line 53, in tm
TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the ``tm`` code? What's the difference between your sample data and the entire dataset? The error is being raised in such function, and what is happening is that there are rows in your whole dataset for which transformation(s) made within ``tm`` function raise this exception.

Comment: Post your udf code here ... I think one of method is expecting one parameter but somehow two parameters are going in.

Comment: It works with small dataset probably because there are no data entries in it that trigger the problem in your code. Show the full source of `tm`.